# Simplification of an expectation

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, expectation-maximization

While attempting to simplify a combination of expectations, I'm stuck at a particular term whose simplification I'm unable to deduce.

The term to be simplified is: $\mathbb{E}[X^{T}F^{T}FX]$

where $F$ is a given matrix of $\dim(p,n)$ while $X$ is a $\dim(n,p)$ matrix where each of its rows is a vector generated from the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,K)$ and $K$ is the covariance matrix.
In other words, the rows ${R_1, R_2 \ldots R_n}$ of $X$ are random vector that follows the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,K)$.

Any help / hint in order to simplify the expectation in terms of $F$ and $K$ would be very useful for my work.

Comment: Hint: consider using the trace operator to switch the order of terms in the integral.

Comment: @Xi'an: Could you please elaborate on this? I'm not familiar with these operations.

Comment: @Xi'an: Can you please provide a detailed answer as I'm unable to go forth the hint you've provided.

Comment: This answer has been asked already [on X validated.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/282597/7224)

Comment: @Xi'an: That question is not the same, here there are matrices not vectors, so trace cannot be used, at least not directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stochastic matrix $X$ have each row a vector with multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, K)$. You did not specify if the rows $R_j^T$ are independent, but I will assume that.

So let $X =\begin{pmatrix} R_1^T \\ R_2^T \\ \vdots \\ R_n^T\end{pmatrix}$ and $F^T=\begin{pmatrix} f_1^T \\f_2^T \\ \vdots \\ f_n^T \end{pmatrix}$.Then we can write
$$
 FX = \begin{pmatrix} f_1 & f_2 & \dots & f_n \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} R_1^T \\ R_2^T \\ \vdots \\ R_n^T\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{j=1}^n f_j R_j^T
$$ and using this
$$
X^T F^T F X= \sum_j R_j f_j^T \cdot \sum_k f_k R_k^T =\sum_j\sum_k R_j f_j^T f_k R_k^T
$$
note that $f_j^T f_k$ is a number, and by the assumed independence (and expectation zero of $R_j$) the terms for $j \not= k$ are zero.

Then we can conclude that
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\DeclareMathOperator{\trace}{\mathrm{trace}}
\begin{align}
\E X^T F^T F X &= \sum_j \E R_j f_j^T f_j R_j^T =\sum_j f_j^T f_j \E R_j R_j^T \\
&= K \sum_j f_j^T f_j = K \trace F^T F
\end{align}
$$
There is a superficial similarity to the question [Confused about finding expectation of vector multiplied by matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282597/confused-about-finding-expectation-of-vector-multiplied-by-matrix), but the trace trick used there cannot be used in this case.

Comment: Not sure if we can state the the equivalence $\sum_j \mathbb{E} R_j f_j^T f_j R_j^T =\sum_j f_j^T f_j \mathbb{E} R_j R_j^T$ in the last step. The rest of the proof looks fine.

Comment: Why not? The matrix $F$ is a constant, and $f_j^T f_j$ is a scalar?

Comment: Yes, right. Mixed up some notations. Thanks for the answer.